# Converter is not called when using Simple Framework

Tags: java, simple-framework

Here is a simple class

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class Foo{
    @ElementList(entry = "Test", required = false, inline=true)
    @Convert(TestConverter.class)
    public List<MyClass> test = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

    public static class TestConverter implements  Converter<List<MyClass>>
    {
        public List<MyClass> read(InputNode node) {

            return new ArrayList<MyClass>();
        }

        public void write(OutputNode node, List<MyClass> myclass) {
            node.setAttribute("debug", "debug");
        }
    }
}
```

The converter is never called. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The converter is never called. Could anyone shed some light on this?

The cause here: The serializer *doesn't know* about the *`@Convert`*. You have to specify a ***strategy***, telling there's a converter to use.

**Use one of these:**

- [`AnnotationStrategy`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/AnnotationStrategy.html)
- [`RegistryStrategy`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/RegistryStrategy.html)

Using the `AnnotationStrategy`:

Just replace ...

```
Serializer ser = new Persister();
```

with

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());
//                             |----------------------|
```

Of course there's an example for each [**here**](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters).

---

**Some other issues:**

```
@ElementList(entry = "Test", required = false, inline=true)
@Convert(TestConverter.class)
```

This may fail:

> Note that for the above field the ***Element annotation is required***. If
>   this is used with any other XML annotation such as the ***ElementList*** or
>   Text ***annotation then an exception will be thrown***.

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Convert.html

Just *use `@Element` instead*.

**Use `@Override`**

```
@Override /* Better use this */
public List<MyClass> read(InputNode node) {
    // ...
}

@Override /* Better use this */
public void write(OutputNode node, List<MyClass> myclass) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the elucidation.  I can't believe that I completely missed the strategy part while reading the example as you pointed to.  Late night or early morning cannot be a good excuse.